# SQL command if sum = 0 by criteria

Tags: sql, sqlcommand

In my table I have Voucher, Dimension and Amount. Each Voucher is unique, and Dimension is usually similar per two Vouchers. There is also usually an identical positive and negative amount per Voucher for each Dimension. I'm looking for a command that will exclude every Dimension that is summarised to 0.

So far I have

```
Select Dimension,
       Sum(Amount)
From "table"
Group by Dimension;
```

This gives me a table where I can see the summarised amount per Dimension.

How to expand this to give me Voucher with Dimension that doesn't summarize to 0?

The actual table contains 200 000 rows, but I have made an example to illustrate what I'm starting with and what I hope to get as a result:

[Table]

[image: 1]

[Result]

[image: 2]

Comment: Please add a few rows of sample data and the expected result. The question is not clear [to me].

Comment: Try add Sum(Amount) <> 0 after group by. Write a query on top of this query to get the vouchers.

Comment: @praveen forgot the `HAVING` in `HAVING Sum(Amount) <> 0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be like this

To filter rows only with SUM equal 0

```
Select Dimension
From "table"
Group by Dimension
Having Sum(Amount) = 0
```

And make above query as subquery to exclude Dimensions with SUM equal 0

```
SELECT *
FROM "table"
WHERE Dimension NOT IN (
    Select Dimension
    From "table"
    Group by Dimension
    Having Sum(Amount) = 0
)
```

It will return you full records from "table".

At least it should work for MS SQL DBMS.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```sql
Select a.voucher, b.dimension from table a

left join(Select dimension, sum(amount) 
from table 
group by 1
having sum(amount) <> 0) b on a.dimension = b.dimension;
```